# can't integrate ag-grid with Ionic3

Tags: angular, typescript, grid, ionic3

I'm trying to integrate ag-grid with Ionic using the very simple demo grid
It's all squished.Not finding style sheet?

[image]

Here is my source code:
https://github.com/jdchabonneau/blankAgGrid.git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I test your GitHub project. I think your problem is Node Module or CSS path is not found correctly. 
I just include cdn of(**ag-gride.css** and **theme-fresh.css**) is working fine.

Go to index.html file

Add following line.

```
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ag-grid/13.0.2/styles/ag-grid.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ag-grid/13.0.2/styles/theme-fresh.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Look That

[image]

> You can test your project just including CDN. Hope this will help you.